# How can I send this POST request with cURL?

Tags: api, curl, post, request

Here is the HTML code

```
<form method="POST" action="https://testnet.demo.example.org/api/v1/invoices">
      <input type="hidden" name="storeId" value="LLKZz9dtP7DYvEUDq73K59EKvjMWox7nvnUhfCGMKsux" />
      <input type="hidden" name="price" value="10" />
      <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD" />
      <input type="image" class="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

When I click the "submit" button, it redirects me to a random url like this,

```
https://testnet.demo.example.org/invoice?id=KuVFG7YFmfArccjkmBPhyg
```

How can I send this POST request using command line using cURL and get that random invoice url?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command:

```
curl --verbose  --request "POST" "https://testnet.demo.example.org/api/v1/invoices?storeId=LLKZz9dtP7DYvEUDq73K59EKvjMWox7nvnUhfCGMKsux&price=10&currency=USD"
```

You can always use tools like [this curl-builder](https://curl-builder.herokuapp.com/), but I highly suggest to use tools like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to make api calls.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is not returning me the randomly generated URL

Comment: I'm getting this: `Status Code: 404; Not Found`